# How do I order conditionals in an if statement, java?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
public void setType(int side1, int side2, int side3)
{

    if((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3) && side1+side2+side3 > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("EQUILATERAL");
    }
        else if((side1 == side2) || (side2 == side3) || (side3 == side1) && side1+side2+side3 > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("ISOSCELES");
        }
        else if(((side1 > side2+side3) && (side1 < side3 - side2 )) || (side1 < side2-side3) || (side1+side2+side3 <= 0))
        {
            System.out.println("DOES NOT FORM A TRIANGLE");
        }   
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("SCALENE");
        }
}
```

The goal of the program is to determine the triangle type three ints create. The program is outputting ISOSCELES for int 0,0,0. Is there a certain order I need to use when combining || and && conditionals?

Comment: You're missing brackets. (Same reason `System.out.println(1+2*3);` prints 7 and not 9, your isosceles test returns true and not false)

Comment: Use a debugger (the ones in Eclipse and IDEA are excellent) to step through your code and find where it's going off the rails.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a parens. Here is the corrected line, with a parens added around the ORs.

```
 else if( (side1 == side2) || (side2 == side3) || (side3 == side1)) && side1+side2+side3 > 0))
```

Comment: Note : you also missed one at start.